# After Submit action is not working in the infopath list form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, custom-list, custom-form

I have provided a 'Submit' button in an InfoPath list form which submits the data to the SharePoint list and in the 'After Submit' I have provided the option to "Open New Form". But the form is not loading an new instance upon clicking this button.

I have tried to give the rules instead. But the problem is, I have a 'People or Group' field which is not being cleared upon submit even with such a rule.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why Open new form is not working for you.

For clearing a People field you need to have 3 actions to clear

1. Displayname
2. AccountID
3. AccountType